# How do I grant Read Access to FILESTREAM data in a table but not grant SELECT access?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2016, filestream

Problem:

I want users to be able to download data stored in a table that contains a FILESTREAM column.  Each file is typically 200 to 500 MBytes.  I however do not want to grant the user SELECT access (specifically SELECT *) to the table.  I was able to create a stored procedure that provides the Path / Transaction Context.  However if I do not grant select permissions on the table the SqlFileStream() class fails to open due to a permission error.

If I grant the SELECT permission I risk a user performing a SELECT * on the table and watch the server die as it is trying to return gigabytes of information.

I believe I have a solution. 
I think I can deny select permissions to the table.  The only reasonable way to retrieve the data from the FileStream table is through the application.  I can use an Application Role which has permission to the table to perform the download.  I will try this out, I was hoping to not have to make this more complicated...

Comment: Are you concerned about the users selecting all rows from the table (your `SELECT *` scenario)? Or, about users executing `SELECT FileContents FROM myTable` with no `WHERE` clause, possibly returning thousands of rows (and thus, thousands of files)? Do users have the ability to query the database directly, or only through an application?

Comment: Users require the ability to select directly from the table.  I provide an application to allow users to download the file(s) via FileStream and to view data.  The data I'm storing is all sensor measurement and engineering data.  Their is a requirement to allow them to use other tools to access the data.  For example using R or Python to perform their own custom analysis.  I don't think it is reasonable to expect each user to remember not to query the table with the FileStream column.

Comment: What about providing a view with all columns but the FileStream column - do you think you could get your users used to using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to restrict SELECT access to a set number of rows.

If the users don't need access to the entire table, but just their "own" rows, you could configure [row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security) (SQL 2016 and up) to restrict access to only what they need. This will not prevent the user from performing a `SELECT *`, but it will restrict the volume of data returned if they do run one.

Ultimately, this is the kind of situation which would be best solved by not allowing users to have any direct access to the table, and instead have the data returned via app code which can be controlled to not run a `SELECT *`.

Comment: I agree the best solution is to not allow anyone to access the table except for the application itself.  I managed to get this to work but it was a big pain.  Things like application roles etc did not work.  I had to implement impersonation in my application to impersonate a user then the impersonated user had to connect to the database in order to retrieve the data.